# camera quality in Flash

Tags: flash, video, webcam

I have this simple code to access the webcam:

```
var camera = Camera.getCamera();

camera.setLoopback(true);
camera.setQuality( 0, 100 );

if (camera != null){
    myVid.attachCamera(camera);
}
```

The quality of the video is extremely bad, with big compression fragments.
I am using a built-in webcam as test, so I don't expect too much. But what I see is not normal for my webcam.

So how do I set the quality of the video?
I cannot see any difference in quality if I remove the setQuality call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the quality is bad because you are testing it with compression:  `camera.setLoopback(true);`.

from the documentation for [setLoopback()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setLoopback%28%29):

> Specifies whether to use a compressed
>   video stream for a local view of the
>   camera. This method is applicable only
>   if you are transmitting video using
>   Flash Media Server; setting compress
>   to true lets you see more precisely
>   how the video will appear to users
>   when they view it in real time.
>
> Although a compressed stream is useful
>   for testing purposes, such as
>   previewing video quality settings, it
>   has a significant processing cost,
>   because the local view is not simply
>   compressed; it is compressed, edited
>   for transmission as it would be over a
>   live connection, and then decompressed
>   for local viewing.